# Assembly Coroutines

Tags: c, assembly, x86, coroutine

I'm trying to create a coroutine implementation for fun to be used with C programs. I'm running on Windows 64bit, Intel x86-64. I'm compiling my function with CodeBlocks 17.12 which is using mingw32-gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1). My current implementation segfaults with 0xC0000005 (access violation) when I try and call printf in the coroutine. I'm at a loss for what the problem is and how to debug it.

I'm getting my inspiration from:

1. [Fast fibers/coroutines under x64 Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429345/fast-fibers-coroutines-under-x64-windows) which links to:
2. https://the8bitpimp.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/coroutines-x64-and-visual-studio/

### main.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void swap32(void*, void*);

typedef struct {
    uintptr_t sp;
} Coro;

Coro mainco;
Coro otherco;

uint8_t costack[1024];

void cofunc(Coro* coro)
{
    printf("Hello");

    unsigned i;
    for(i = 10; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("coro: %d\n", i);

        swap32(&otherco, &mainco);
    }
}

void prepare(Coro* coro, void* stack, unsigned stacksize, void (*func)(Coro*))
{
    uint32_t* ptr;
    ptr    = (uint32_t*)((uint8_t*)stack + stacksize);
    ptr   -= 7;
    ptr[0] = 1;                 /* edi */
    ptr[1] = 2;                 /* esi */
    ptr[2] = 3;                 /* ebx */
    ptr[3] = (uint32_t)(ptr+5); /* ebp TODO: fix? */
    ptr[4] = (uint32_t)func;
    ptr[5] = (uint32_t)swap32;  /* return instruction address TODO: fix? */
    coro->sp = ptr;
}

int main()
{
    prepare(&otherco, costack, 1024, cofunc);

    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("main:  %d\n", i);

        swap32(&mainco, &otherco);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### coro.S

Assembly in AT&T syntax.

```
.global _swap32

// ecx: context for the coroutine that is being paused.
// edx: context for the coroutine that is being resumed.
_swap32:
    mov 4(%esp), %ecx
    mov 8(%esp), %edx
    # Save registers
    push %ebp
    push %ebx
    push %esi
    push %edi
    # Save old stack
    mov %esp, (%ecx)
    # Load new stack
    mov (%edx), %esp
    # Restore registers
    pop %edi
    pop %esi
    pop %ebx
    pop %ebp
    ret
```

Here is my general understanding:

1. When a coroutine yields/pauses, it needs to store its stack pointer, instruction pointer, and registers somewhere.
2. In my implementation, the return address (next instruction pointer) is stored in the C call to `swap32` because the calling `swap32` pushes the return address to the current stack.
3. `swap32` saves the current stack pointer then swaps the stack pointer for the destination coroutine so that when `ret` is finally executed, the saved instruction pointer for the destination coroutine is called.
4. A coroutine is initialized by setting up a stack frame as if it had called `swap32`. In my implementation, the register state is saved in the stack. Therefore, the initialized coroutine's stack would look like this (with decreasing addresses):

   ```
   function parameters    <--- start of function's stack
   return address         <--- where a normal ebp would point to
   swap32 return address  <--- pushed because of call to swap32
   saved context          <--- pushed because swap32 saves context to current stack
   ```

   That way, `swap32` pops the saved context, followed by `ret` popping the saved function and resuming the coroutine.

What I see is this: if I remove the calls to `printf` from `cofunc`, then the coroutine yields back to main successfully. If I add the calls to `printf` back to `cofunc`, then my program crashes. So here is where my understanding runs out.

### Question:

Why does it crash with `printf` and not crash without? Is it because I haven't initialized the coroutine correctly or is there another reason for it to be crashing?

Comment: Just a guess: If this is _64_ bit, are the `mov` instructions in `swap32` correct [and the amount of save/restore space]? You're using (e.g.) `%ecx` instead of `%rcx`, etc. The linked example is for 64 bit [and uses the "r" forms of the registers]. The ABI may be different, notably the "shadow space", for 32 bit mode. Also, I'm not sure if the asm syntax is intel (`mov dst,src`) or AT&T (`mov src,dst`). First line of `swap32` says intel (i.e. save `%ecx` to stack), but the `%esp` move insts say AT&T (i.e. they look reversed)

Comment: It's AT&T syntax. The linked example is 64 bit but I'm building it for 32 bit. I'll clarify `%ecx` and `%edx` in the question. `%ecx` is set to the current context that is being suspended and `%edx` is set to the destination context that is being resumed. For example, `main()` calls `swap32(&mainco, &otherco)` which sets `%ecx` to `&mainco` (current context) and `%edx` to `&otherco` (destination context).

Comment: @thndrwrks You can't just take a 64 bit example and build it for 32 bit because the calling conventions are different.  Make sure to pay attention to that.

Comment: I believe stacks have certain alignment requirements on x64 but I don't remember the requirements. Something like a multiple of 16 bytes plus 8?

Comment: What is the crash?

Comment: @fuz Yeah I've used the linked example as a hint for writing the code in the question for 32-bit.

Comment: @user253751 The program raises the SIGSEGV signal and returns error code 0xC0000005 which is access violation.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to find out which line of (assembly?) code crashes?

Comment: The crashing instruction is `unlock+4062` which is `mov %eax,(%esp)`. I'm also trying to fix the alignment of the stack which is probably wrong in the code listed in the question.

Comment: Should the coroutine's stack be located in a particular section of memory?

Comment: Doh I'm dumb. I think I just figured it out. Alignment was not an issue. The stack for the coroutine was **way** too small. Resizing the coroutine's stack to 8192 bytes causes the program to not crash!