# Perf: Could not find an useful description of "branch-load-misses" metric

Tags: linux, performance, perf, intel-vtune

I'm trying to show that the stalls due to branch misprediction may be reduced due to a certain optimization. My intuition suggests this could be due to a reduction in the stall cycles related to loads that delay the branch outcome.

For this, I was planning to use the Linux Perf utility to get the Hardware performance counter values. There is a related metric called **branch-load-misses**, however, no useful description is provided.

Can anybody please confirm if this is the right metric to use? If not, please suggest a related metric that could be of help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Linux `perf` has the `branches` and `branch-misses` counters, on Intel x86 these map to `BR_INST_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES` and `BR_MISP_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES` which measure all retired branches, and all retired mispredicted branches, respectively.

`perf list` also includes `branch-loads` and `branch-load-misses` but no explanation of what they do. Weirdly, the kernel sources only reference them in the context of PowerPC [1]. On x86, it seems they are just mapped to `branches` and `branch-misses` as they return identical values:

```
$ perf stat -e branches,branch-misses,branch-loads,branch-load-misses -- /bin/true

 Performance counter stats for '/bin/true':

           415,881      branches
             8,787      branch-misses             #    2.11% of all branches
           415,881      branch-loads
             8,787      branch-load-misses
```

Regarding your original question, keep in mind that the impact of branches comes from two components: the number of mispredicted branches, and the branch resolution time (time to compute the actual branch outcome, which potentially depends on long-latency loads). The former can be measured using the `branch-misses` event. To quantify the latter, you may be better of with something like TopDown analysis [2].

[1] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/powerpc/perf/generic-compat-pmu.c

[2] https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Top-Down_Analysis

Answer (score 2):

The **branch-loads** and **branch-load-misses** events are equal to **branch-instructions** and **branch-misses** events.

They are just two events of type PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE, which is another abstraction for hardware cache events. The BPU is cache-like.

```
$ strace -e perf_event_open perf stat -e branch-loads,branch-load-misses  ls
perf_event_open({type=PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE, size=0x88 /* PERF_ATTR_SIZE_??? */, config=PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_BPU|PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ<<8|PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_ACCESS<<16, ...}, 2512745, -1, -1, PERF_FLAG_FD_CLOEXEC) = 4
perf_event_open({type=PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE, size=0x88 /* PERF_ATTR_SIZE_??? */, config=PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_BPU|PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ<<8|PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS<<16, ...}, 2512745, -1, -1, PERF_FLAG_FD_CLOEXEC) = 5
```

And they are finaly mapped to hw events BR_INST_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES and BR_MISP_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES.

```
static __initconst const u64 skl_hw_cache_event_ids
                [PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MAX]
                [PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_MAX]
                [PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MAX] =
{
 ...
 [ C(BPU ) ] = {
    [ C(OP_READ) ] = {
        [ C(RESULT_ACCESS) ] = 0xc4,    /* BR_INST_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES */
        [ C(RESULT_MISS)   ] = 0xc5,    /* BR_MISP_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES */
    },
    [ C(OP_WRITE) ] = {
        [ C(RESULT_ACCESS) ] = -1,
        [ C(RESULT_MISS)   ] = -1,
    },
    [ C(OP_PREFETCH) ] = {
        [ C(RESULT_ACCESS) ] = -1,
        [ C(RESULT_MISS)   ] = -1,
    },
 },
 ...
}
```

More mappings for intel Skylake (see driver arch/x86/events/intel/core.c):

- cache-misses: LONGEST_LAT_CACHE.MISS
- cache-references: LONGEST_LAT_CACHE.REFERENCE
- branch-loads: BR_INST_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES
- branch-load-misses: BR_MISP_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES
- L1-dcache-loads: MEM_INST_RETIRED.ALL_LOADS
- L1-dcache-load-misses: L1D.REPLACEMENT
- L1-dcache-stores: MEM_INST_RETIRED.ALL_STORES
- L1-icache-load-misses: ICACHE_64B.IFTAG_MISS
- LLC-loads: OFFCORE_RESPONSE
- LLC-load-misses: OFFCORE_RESPONSE
- LLC-stores: OFFCORE_RESPONSE
- LLC-store-misses: OFFCORE_RESPONSE
- dTLB-loads: MEM_INST_RETIRED.ALL_LOADS
- dTLB-load-misses: DTLB_LOAD_MISSES.WALK_COMPLETED
- dTLB-stores: MEM_INST_RETIRED.ALL_STORES
- dTLB-store-misses: DTLB_STORE_MISSES.WALK_COMPLETED
- iTLB-loads: ITLB_MISSES.STLB_HIT
- iTLB-load-misses: ITLB_MISSES.WALK_COMPLETED

More mappings for ARM PMUv3 (see driver drivers/perf/arm_pmuv3.c):

- cache-misses: L1D_CACHE_REFILL
- cache-references: L1D_CACHE
- branch-loads: BR_PRED
- branch-load-misses: BR_MIS_PRED
- L1-dcache-loads: L1D_CACHE
- L1-dcache-load-misses: L1D_CACHE_REFILL
- L1-icache-loads: L1I_CACHE
- L1-icache-load-misses: L1I_CACHE_REFILL
- LLC-loads: LL_CACHE_RD
- LLC-load-misses: LL_CACHE_MISS_RD
- dTLB-loads: L1D_TLB
- dTLB-load-misses: L1D_TLB_REFILL
- iTLB-loads: L1I_TLB
- iTLB-load-misses: L1I_TLB_REFILL

Answer (score 0):

For measuring the branch prediction and the branch misprediction rate, you can use the VTune Profiler.
Download link:
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/vtune-profiler.html#gs.bh5zrq

Just create a custom VTune analysis with 2 events:

- `BR_INST_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES`
- `BR_MISP_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES`

You'll need to manually divide one by another to get the ratio, though.

`BR_INST_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES`:‌ Counts all (macro) branch instructions retired.

`BR_MISP_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES`: Counts all the retired branch instructions that were miss predicted by the processor.

A branch misprediction occurs when the processor incorrectly predicts the destination of the branch.

When the misprediction is discovered at execution, all the instructions executed in the wrong (speculative) path must be discarded, and the processor must start fetching from the correct path.

In case you don't know - custom analysis in VTune can be created by selecting any pre-defined analysis and pressing the 'Customize...' button in the top-right corner.

E.g., you can select Microarchitecture Exploration, uncheck all checkboxes there, press 'Customize...', scroll down to the table with CPU events and uncheck all not needed/add needed events.

Regards

Comment: Ok, yes those are useful HW events to look at, but what HW event does Linux `perf` map its `branch-loads` and `branch-load-misses` to?  You're not answering that part, or the querent's attempt to measure the total misprediction *penalties* rather than just the misprediction *rate*.

Comment: (Linux `perf stat` already calculates the miss rate if you ask it to measure both `branches` and `branch-misses`, which I think on Intel HW maps to `br_misp_retired.all_branches` or `br_misp_retired.all_branches_pebs`)

Comment: And yes the CPU has to discard uops from the wrong path, but the surrounding code and microarchitectural conditions can have an effect on how many that is, and how much overall throughput that costs.  [Avoid stalling pipeline by calculating conditional early](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49932119) discuses one way that branch misses can be cheaper, by *not* having the branch condition be the end of a long dep chain that can't be confirmed for a long time.