# Optimize Android Java loop that copies an array with some elements zeroed, according to a FloatBuffer mask array

Tags: java, android, parallel-processing, simd, renderscript

I have a function as below in Android which is a bit slow and is a bottleneck in my real-time app. I was thinking to somehow make it faster, maybe through GPU or any possible methods. What are ways to make it faster, more efficient using parallelization?

```
private int[] getArray (ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
int[] array = new int[width * height];

FloatBuffer fb = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < width* height; i++) {
    float probability = 1 - floatBuffer.get();
    if (probability > 0.9) {
        array[i] = originalBuffer[i];
    }
  }
return array;
}
```

The context is for segmentation task. Basically, a ML model returns a mask in bytebuffer. I pass it to this function to make the background pink. [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/bc243262d40eba8eeac12556fe756450b692019a/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/segmenter/SegmentationGraphic.java#L75) it is for reference.

Comment: Loop unrolling 2x or 4x is always worth a try. Avoiding floats entirely and working with scaled integers could well be much faster depending on the platform. I take it that your runtime initialises arrays to zero for you? Otherwise 10% of your array ends up with whatever happened to be in the allocated memory.

Comment: Yes `int[] array` should get all zero in the function. A 10x speedup would be good.

Comment: @MartinBrown: For compilers that can auto-vectorize, manual unrolling scalar source can defeat that or make it worse.  But good point about initializing the new `array`: instead of doing that separately, make every loop iteration unconditionally write `array[i]` - that's much easier for compilers to auto-vectorize because they don't have to worry about inventing writes.  Like `array[i] = (fb.get() < 0.1) ? originalBuffer[i] : 0.0;`.  For x86 with SSE2, that should be one `cmpps` and using the compare result as an AND mask to zero some elements with `andps`.  ARM / AArch64 ASIMD works the same.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/dqcT6fP96 shows a C version of this auto-vectorizing for AArch64 with GCC or clang.  Making the array write unconditional, and the `orig[i]` read via a temp variable, were the keys.  So worth trying the equivalent in Java.

Comment: @Mary Can you clarify the purpose of your code, i.e. why a ByteBuffer input with a  int [w*h] output.

Comment: It's for selfie segmentation. Basically a ML model returns a mask in bytebuffer. I pass it to this function to make background pink: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/bc243262d40eba8eeac12556fe756450b692019a/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/segmenter/SegmentationGraphic.java#L75

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment) But what you can easily do: Replace

```
float probability = 1 - floatBuffer.get();
if (probability > 0.9) {
```

by

```
if (floatBuffer.get() < 0.1) {
```

And: I honestly don't know whether the compiler writes a machine code that calculates `width*height` in **every** loop pass for the abort criterion (I hope/think **not**). But give it a try: add the line

```
int product = width*height;
int[] array = new int[product];
```

and then set

```
for (int i = 0; i < product; i++) {
```

In this way, you have eliminated all arithmetic operations (apart of the indispensable `i++` and `<`) in the loop.

Comment: Replacing the conditional store with `array[i] = condition ? orig[i] : 0` could lead to branchless asm and make a *much* bigger speed difference if the branching isn't predictable. It also makes auto-vectorization plausible and easy if a JIT is going to look for it; see my comments under the question.

Comment: The FP optimization is something compilers might not do for you and is a good idea in the source.  (e.g. GCC and clang don't, without `-ffast-math` for a C version: https://godbolt.org/z/eMEzv4o3K).  But hoisting the `product = width*height` is something even a JIT compiler can do easily; there's no aliasing to sort out since these are primitive types not Objects, and they're function args.  You might do `int len = width * height` *anyway* just to avoid repeating yourself in the allocation separate from the loop bound.

Comment: Thanks. These are good, but not really answering the parallelism I'm looking for.

Comment: I did these 2 var changes: `int product = width*height;` and `if (floatBuffer.get() < 0.1)`. I didn't notice a change on the speed tho. I'll try the condition now: `array[i] = condition ? orig[i] : 0`

Answer (score 1):

This will very likely compile / JIT to branchy asm because your loop only stores to `array[i]` on some iterations.  Branchless asm is probably faster [if the pattern isn't predictable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array), and that also enables auto-vectorization if the compiler / JIT is smart enough, like GCC and clang do for a C or C++ version.  [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:121,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:121,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:121,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:121,startLineNumber:14),source:%27//+%23include+%3Cvector%3E++//+its+construtor+zeros+even+if+we+don!%27t+want+that,+and+push_back+one+at+a+time+could+reallocate+defeating+vectorization%0A//+well+maybe+with+reserve+and+push_back+if+the+compiler!%27s+sufficiently+clever%0A//+But+here+I!%27m+just+demoing+the+optimization,+with+the+simplest+code+possible,+not+good+C%2B%2B+style.%0A%0A%23include+%3Cstddef.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+restrict+__restrict++//+promise+that+arrays+don!%27t+overlap+for+fewer+checks+before+the+vectorized+part%0Aint+*mask_array(size_t+len,+const+int+*restrict+orig,+void+*restrict+mask_bytestream)%0A%7B%0A++++//+GNU+C+strict-aliasing-safe+way+to+point+a+float*+at+an+unaligned+byte-stream%0A++++typedef+float+unaligned_aliasing_float+__attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias))%3B%0A++++auto+mask+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3Cunaligned_aliasing_float*%3E(mask_bytestream)%3B%0A%0A++++int+*dst+%3D+new+int%5Blen%5D%3B++//+normally+you!%27d+use+vector%3Cint%3E+dst(len)%3B+//++but+that+would+waste+time+zeroing+it+first%0A++++for+(size_t+i+%3D+0+%3B+i+%3C+len+%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++++++//dst%5Bi%5D+%3D+(mask%5Bi%5D+%3C+0.1f)+%3F+orig%5Bi%5D+:+0.0f%3B++//+might+never+access+whole+parts+of+orig%5B%5D%0A++++++++int+tmp_orig+%3D+orig%5Bi%5D%3B++//+unconditionally+access+orig%5Bi%5D,+otherwise+compiler+can!%27t+invent+loads+that+might+fault%0A++++++++dst%5Bi%5D+%3D+(mask%5Bi%5D+%3C+0.1f)+%3F+tmp_orig+:+0%3B++//+might+never+access+whole+parts+of+orig%5B%5D%0A++++++++//dst%5Bi%5D+%3D+((1-mask%5Bi%5D)+%3E+0.9f)+%3F+tmp_orig+:+0%3B++//+with+slower+subtract%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+dst%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%232%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:51.962373697113,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20+-march%3Dx86-64-v3%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.962373697113,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armv8-clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20+-Rpass%3Dloop-vectorize%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:30,endLineNumber:39,positionColumn:30,positionLineNumber:39,selectionStartColumn:30,selectionStartLineNumber:39,startColumn:30,startLineNumber:39),source:2,wantOptInfo:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+armv8-a+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:100,l:%274%27,m:69.57862281603289,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:2,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+armv8-a+clang+17.0.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:30.421377183967113,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:48.037626302887006,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).  (Like most SIMD ISAs, AArch64 NEON has SIMD float compares to produce a mask of `0` / `-1` elements which works great to bitwise AND another vector, zeroing elements or not.)

Compilers are generally reluctant to invent writes because that can be a thread-safety problem (for arrays that any other thread might have a reference to).  And inventing reads from  `originalBuffer` could go past the end of the array: it would be valid to call your function with an `originalBuffer` of length 100, but a `FloatBuffer` such that `if (probability > 0.9)` was false for all elements past that.

Using `int tmp_orig = orig[i];`
`array[i] = (fb.get() < 0.1f) ? tmp_orig : 0;` fixes both these problems.

`1-x > 0.9` is a slow way to write `x < 0.1`.  (And a compiler won't translate for you, since neither 0.9 nor 0.1 are exactly representable as float or double).  Speaking of float vs. double, `0.9` or `0.1` have type `double`, which forces the compiler to convert float to double for the compare (an extra `fcvt` instruction).  **Use `x < 0.1f` to allow a `float` comparison.**

---

Godbolt has Android Java tools, including the optimizing dex2oat compiler (whatever that is), so I could look at AArch64 asm for Java source.  If I could get something to compile: on any errors, the compiler output is basically the `--help` output, nothing helpful to telling you what it didn't like about the program.

I wrote a version that uses `float[]` instead of a ByteBuffer for simplicity since I was able to get that to compile.  `fb.get()` or `.getFloat()` should be equivalent to `mask[i]` to iterate through the bytebuffer, that's hopefully a drop-in replacement.

```
class Example {
    // Simplified example that compiles without any extra stuff.
    // the same thing with a ByteBuffer and .getFloat() hopefully works the same way
    static int[] getArray_non_fb (float[] mask, int [] originalBuffer, int len) {
        int[] array = new int[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
            int tmp_orig = originalBuffer[i];  // unconditional read
            array[i] = (mask[i] < 0.1f) ? tmp_orig : 0;  // unconditional write
            // bytebuffer.getFloat() instead of mask[i] hopefully compiles the same
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

This compiles branchlessly ([**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoY%2BmKo86ALTamANyakl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAFcWBhAAVgA2Um8AGTwGTAA5IIAjTGIJAA5SAAdUBUIPBj9A4LDI3Pz3AVj4pJZU9K4sl0w3QqECJmICYqCQrgBmZ0xXKoYOroIaxJS0zOdO7t7SwYXJ6bqGzIBKZ1QA4mR2DjwWXO6AajtHADoGDxuAKgBSAYAhZ40AQVPzgiuHEwbgF3LQnq8Pt9Pl8APQwi5YVR6VBMf4AeWy7hYeAAXnFgBdkgE6OgLngFBcCAhMAjMFQmAFaAQbtC4RcAJL/dCoTAKBhgDj/eytIjEXE0on/VEXehMBT/AJKCnIFyU1AXFhMADWEuIxmQCHoCgpXy%2BhwQ4UkGqYBriNLQWBZ32QRmNF2wqlY2XoF2eAHZIV8LsGLvLUXhkGTBM9Qh9QgARC7ATAEM16gCeAH0GAJM1RkhdqLQUQQY3HE5qFFrSFH/mWY4mSHhgHExG8AlQqGka3F/vQGNtfQHoSHRxc2b2ZYxfQNEwB3KxUi6PC7U5sIUvvEdj4Nw3v1hMXLoZmeJ%2BJz2tlhfoJcrtfADcNiHbnf72MNo/EE%2BvM%2BYC9vt5%2ByfLcoW%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%2BJqLmy0iCCx5iC0S5JMfcji5TZ1j%2BeIHjOvAyDoJJ2DEoQ7yZYGFD%2B3QzDsKwt4yZZ0c7PysUCUSgm2xFzzirZMqBAqgQQrCiKtdUr91M8uCi2F9jiE4lMeOQ%2BCMqy3LDbct2ncKuWMJK83AoKK3aFGmq6sUsduvMncWraz8M3F4Mk8eGFWT65PQ06aGcYUABHAIukwCBJ3%2BlhNYT0dU%2BINDa%2BXC5a8zodrITnOIb9bvme%2BDhdloThQl4EIOC0UhUE4L5AosKwLgAKUBUN9kOGksIGPReAITRh92akIrmHjSC1MIBhucINHCABOLgpEkP0NAySQ9GkUeOEkXgWAkDQNCkEntPWeHBeAKBAIA/eU9h6kDgLAGAiAUCoEWvQMgFAIALWyEtdI1wmDWERMiVE1gjC1XlHwOgtViAQIgMkA%2BpBqLMGIOmTgPAGGtmYWiZI2gRSsN4AtNggg0QMFoCwmBpAsBEmAD4MQtAIHcF4FgTUJhxDiPwGFNowp5HT0wKoVoIJjjT17CMehP1kh6mYX4LA9CCBij/go3YJFboKAAGp4D/BiRgfCZCCBEGIdgUgfHyCUGoehuguCGGMKYBelgbB4MMHgZIEDIC7FQJiQo8jeCoGFF%2BKwvJ4C7BaG0TwEBvDLH6FEQKGwAYSByHkKORR/B9FqRUBp1T6hzAiUUsYEwlhNJWMMUY7RFhTDtJsTpaw%2BklAqWGbo7SthyT2AcI4%2BgR5jwnvQ0BFwvgACUAAqG0iF9lRLyf4EBcCECBtvPQ2w94H22LsC%2BAwZIDAyHfP0fo9B%2BgyH6cI4RXkDD9IYTgP9SB/0%2BTcX5khLShHfuEUIXBQh3yGMArJnBwGQNINArQux4FIP2AQbIIJyCUCwTghIrBji7IOYQrapDTm8EwEFJs6B9BBL8eIQJ/BBCKBUOocR4TSDVSYNkPhayODjyAZszgaIQREv%2BB9bZ%2BzDl0pOfKQsfhUHo23nJO5MCHmkGPlgdIZ8v6gr/l8m4egBihBtZIUIfoBiSDfhoP00hUUz3Rc4TF2LD7nxANCm4AxkWvwyKEUIegH4OsiF/AYGzxGgL1Ti8Vu8wX/0AR6xNWL7m7ByfkTwkggA%3D%3D)), note the `csel` (AArch64 conditional select, like x86 `cmov`) instead of `b.hi` for the original.  And with no `fcvt` or `fsub`.

```
    0x0000109c    cmp w1, w24                 # w1 is the loop counter i
    0x000010a0    b.ge #+0x30 (addr 0x10d0)
    0x000010a4    add w2, w22, #0xc (12)      # re-generate a pointer to originalBuffer
    0x000010a8    add w3, w23, #0xc (12)      # same for mask
    0x000010ac    ldr s1, [x2, x1, lsl #2]    # mask[i] load float
    0x000010b0    ldr w2, [x3, x1, lsl #2]    # int tmp_orig = originalBuffer[i]
    0x000010b4    add w3, w0, #0xc (12)       # generate pointer to output array[]
    0x000010b8    fcmp s1, s0                  # fcmp mask[i], 0.1f
    0x000010bc    csel w2, w2, wzr, lo         # conditionally zero tmp_orig
    0x000010c0    str w2, [x3, x1, lsl #2]     # array[i] = ternary result
    0x000010c4    add w1, w1, #0x1 (1)         # ++i
    0x000010c8    ldr x21, [x21]             # WTF?  Linked list pointer chasing creates a latency bottleneck?
     StackMap[3]   native_pc=0x10cc, dex_pc=0x4, register_mask=0xc00001, stack_mask=0b
    0x000010cc    b #-0x30 (addr 0x109c)
```

This appears to be the inner loop.  It *is* a loop, and the only part of the asm that contains `fcmp`.  It seems pretty horrible, with the condition at the top and an unconditional branch at the bottom, [unlike an idiomatic asm loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump), and redundant integer `add` that could have been hoisted out of the loop.

This isn't auto-vectorized.  And the `ldr x21, [x21]` limits the loop to at best 1 iteration per 3 to 4 clocks (load-use latency) if that's really there in the asm that would actually run.  No idea what that's for; perhaps so another thread can change a memory location to make this thread fault and have the JVM regain control in this thread?  Seems like a very expensive way to do that if an instruction like this appears in all loops.

A core like Cortex-A710 ([chipsandcheese](https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/08/11/arms-cortex-a710-winning-by-default/)) could be doing about 4 elements per clock cycle with ASIMD (like clang's AArch64 loop form the C++ version) instead of 1 every 2 (or per 4 with the `ldr x21, [x21]` bottleneck), so an 8x speedup over this branchless asm is theoretically possible.  Or more with SVE if Android enables that.  But I have no clue how to get a JVM to do better, if this is what would actually run on an Android device.

If branch prediction was a problem, this version might run a few times faster than your original, especially if data was hot in some level of cache.

Or not on an out-of-order exec CPU that can see the branch condition several iterations ahead of the `ldr x21, [x21]` dependency chain and already recover from the branch miss without losing any progress on the actual bottleneck.  (*[Avoid stalling pipeline by calculating conditional early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932119/avoid-stalling-pipeline-by-calculating-conditional-early)*)

Again, IDK exactly what that load instruction is doing, but it's a disaster for performance on high-end AArch64 CPUs with wide pipelines (many instructions per clock) and load-use latency higher than 2.

It's also disappointing (but not unexpected) that the code didn't auto-vectorize with ASIMD instructions the way C++ compilers do (see the first paragraph.)  Perhaps there's another JIT optimization pass and this asm isn't what actually executes?

These source transformations make things as easy as possible for a compiler to optimize, but you still need the compiler to do its share of the work.  Or to manually vectorize with SIMD extensions if they're available in Java for Android.

Comment: Thanks. But mask is ByteBuffer, not float. Can you change the argument?

Comment: @Mary: I was assuming `FloatBuffer fb = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();` was just a type-pun, like C++ `reinterpret_cast<float*>` on a `uint8_t*`, except strict-aliasing safe and maybe unaligned, like in my first Godbolt link (where I used a GNU C `may_alias,aligned(1)` typedef).   Presumably `fb.get()` is a drop-in replacement for `mask[i]`; try it yourself with some valid syntax that compiles; I wasn't about to waste time on trial-and-error with that with the terrible toolchain setup on Godbolt where it doesn't tell you what it didn't like about the source.

Comment: Ok. What should I try exactly?

Comment: @Mary: I don't know, I don't use Java and I don't know exactly what a ByteBuffer is.  But if `fb.get()` is an iterator for an array-like object, you should try making the changes I described in the text of my answer to your code.  And the loop body should look like in my Java except with `fb.get() < 0.1f` instead of `mask[i] < 0.1f`.

Comment: @Mary: I checked, `byteBuffer.getFloat()` is just reading the next 4 bytes as a `float`.  So `byteBuffer.getFloat()` is a drop-in replacement for the `mask[i]` I used here just to get something simpler to compile.  In asm it should be identical.  And my C/C++ version with `reinterpret_cast` *is* identical to what a Java ByteBuffer does.  Did you get a chance to try any of this answer's optimizations in your code yet?

Comment: So how should I pass a float[] to the function? Why don't you write byteBuffer.getFloat() inside the function and let the function get ByteBuffer? Any difference?

Comment: @Mary: You don't pass a `float[]` to the function, you pass a ByteBuffer if that's what you have.  I didn't write a version with `byteBuffer.getFloat()` because `fb.get()` didn't compile, and as I said, the Android Java toolchain on https://godbolt.org/ doesn't tell you what's wrong with the code so I wasn't going to spend time guessing.  The point of my answer is the changes I pointed out, not just a code-block you can copy/paste unchanged.  Make the same changes to your version's loop body, except keep your `.getFloat()` instead of indexing a `float[]`.

Comment: Got it. And also you write `int tmp_orig = originalBuffer[i];` but didn't use tmp_orig. does it make a difference if I just use originalBuffer[i] inside the condition?

Comment: I did those changes on the condition to a one-liner. I didn't notice a big difference in speed tho: `array[i] = (fb.get(i) < 0.1f) ? originalBuffer[i] : 0; `

Comment: @Mary: Thanks, updated my answer with that and some other stuff.  I had intended to actually use `tmp_orig` instead of `originalBuffer[i]` again.  My Godbolt link did that, but I missed updating the code in the question after noticing that.  However, the asm was the same: the unused unconditional read (into an unused `tmp_orig`) was sufficient for the compiler to do an unconditional read for `originalBuffer[i]` and use `csel` instead of a branch.  (But if you removed the `int tmp_orig` line, that won't happen.) Search for `csel` in the asm on https://godbolt.org/z/Y3bsevjvz to see for yourself